# button does not appear when i open the keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

i added

```
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

and the button is in ScrollView but I had used MotionLayout,is it because of that?

Comment: Providing a screenshot would better.

Comment: Provide layout xml and MotionScene xml.
The more context the easier it is for people to understand your problem.